# UPdate data in odoo via standard import function?

Tags: csv, import, odoo

I tried desperately to update prices via csv in the standard import of odoo 10.
First did an export to have the id, then import (id,name,price/product_template_21,"foo",15), also tried only name, price.
but it always creates a new product.

is it really possible to update?
I read here that should work, but not with me.

Have a lot of prices to update.

Comment: What id are you exporting? database or external? you should export external ID and import with the same external id